# How to use localisation with Flutter PDF package since PDF Page has no BuildContext?

Tags: flutter, pdf, localization

I'm using Flutter pdf package inside my project (https://pub.dev/packages/pdf). The package generates a document which I show on the screen. I want to add localisation (localised Text fields) into my generated pdf document but AppLocalizations.of(context) requires BuildContext, not just a Context.

As I understood, generated pdf file is not a part of material Scaffold, so there is no way to access BuildContext.
[Page constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMSMS.png)

Any ideas how to get access to BuildContext when I configure localised Text strings in my pdf Page?

I tried to find the answer on package page and package repo, but I have not found any solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

instead of passing the context, try to call AppLocalizations as a singleton without passing the context. some intl libraries provide singlton, if you couldn't find any, try to store the instance in GetIt , or build your own technique and store it in main widget.

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Define a Global Modal
2) Create a Stateless widget
3) Define a Local Modal inside of this widget like :
   

 DrawingModel localModelForDevelop = DrawingModel(
    musteriId: AppLocalizations.of(context).turnBack,

4) in this widget 
    return Container(
            height: Get.height,
            color: AppTheme().kirlibeyaz,
            child: PdfPreview(
              build: (format) => _generatePdf(
                  localModelForDevelop,
                  const PdfPageFormat(21.0 * cm, 29.7 * cm, marginAll: 0.5 * cm),
                  "Test"),),);

5) Define your pdf widget inside of your stateless 
Future<Uint8List> _generatePdf(DrawingModel insidelocalModelForDevelop) async{
you can define finals here  like :
final font = await PdfGoogleFonts.openSansLight();
final fontbold = await PdfGoogleFonts.openSansBold();

final _yourPdf = [
pw.Text('Tarih : ${alocalModelForDevelop.cizimTarihi.toString()}',
style: const pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 8),) ]

pdf.addPage(
// Page Ayarları
      pw.MultiPage(
          theme: pw.ThemeData(defaultTextStyle: pw.TextStyle(font: font)),  
          build: (context) {
            return _yourPdf ;
          }),
    );
```

A bit complicated but it works.